# Tabletop or object detector for indigo

Tags: ros, vrep, tabletop, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to recognize objects on the tabletop, and return their coordinates and sizes to my manipulator, but I want to also run this algorithm in the simulation (v-rep). I have previously written an object recognizer using tabletop_object_detector in ros fuerte using the PR2 pick and place tutorials, and I need to update the code so I can use it with indigo. However, there is no "tabletop_object_detector/TabletopDetection.h" file and the structure of the tabletop has changed as I have downloaded the ORK library (both as ros-indigo library and the source code from website) and looked at its source codes. I checked the website as well, but I couldn't find any tutorials on how to write a code based on the new library and there is no PR2 pick and place tutorial for indigo, so I'm stuck. Could anyone please give an advice on which library should I use, perhaps a tutorial? Or is there any other library which is more easy to use with tutorials and instructions in order to use it within my own code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202338/tabletop-or-object-detector-for-indigo/) by [-_-](https://answers.ros.org/users/21556/-_-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that ORK is the replacement (it also includes a tabletop detector). At least that is what we are using. The messages/datatypes might be different, but the information is still there.

[This](http://wg-perception.github.io/ork_tutorials/tutorial02/tutorial.html) should be the relevant tutorials. At the end you get an ObjectRecognitionResult, which is basically a list of RecognizedObject. If you explicitly want the table information a separate message /table_array is also published (only when using TableTopDetection).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [-_-](https://answers.ros.org/users/21556/-_-/) on 2015-02-03**:
I know that ORK is the replacement library, that is why I installed it, however, since the structure is different I don't know which message types to publish. Could you give a more specific example on how to use the library? Like what is used instead of tabletop_object_detector::TabletopDetection?